# What does this Gradle line do for Android build

Tags: android, gradle

If I have this `build.gradle` file, what would the line `exampleBoolean:true` do?

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        exampleBoolean:true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect it to fail the build, with an error message like:

```
Statement labels may not be used in build scripts.
  In case you tried to configure a property named 'exampleBoolean', replace ':' with '=' or ' ', otherwise it will not have the desired effect.
```

At least, that is what happens if you try it.

Comment: I tried it in my project to see if I could figure it out, and it builds fine! Android Studio also seems to have no problems with it.

Comment: @FiferSheep: With Gradle 2.1, and the Gradle for Android 0.13.2 plugin, you get the error shown in my answer, when adding your statement to the `productFlavors` closure in [this sample project's `build.gradle` file](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/HelloProductFlavors).

Comment: Then it must be because I'm using Gradle 1.12 and plugin 0.12.2

This explains why I couldn't find anything on this online!

Comment: If I changed it to `exampleBoolean=true`, would this set anything in `configuration.properties`?

Comment: @FiferSheep: Sorry, but I do not know what `configuration.properties` is.